Intersection number and linking number of arcs
Part 1:
Let S be a surface with boundary (we assume everything is oriented and compact if necessary). It's classical that we can define the intersection number of any two closed curves. Now I want to define the intersection number of arcs with ends on $\partial S$. It's easy to see this intersection number cannot be well-defined. But if we take two disjoint subsets $A,B\subset \partial S$ and assume the ends of the arc $\alpha$ are on $A$ and the ends of the arc $\beta$ are on $B$, then I think the intersection number of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is well-defined.
It suffices to define a non-degenerate bilinear form $H_1(S,A)\times H_1(S,B)\to \mathbb{Z}$. It looks like Alexander-Poincare duality, but I couldn't obtain it from this duality.
In my memory, an author wrote down something like $H^1(S,A)\cong H_1(S,B)$ in his paper (there must be more conditions on $A$ and $B$, e.g. $A\cup B=\partial S$), but I cannot find it now.
Part 2:
Let $N\subset S^3$ be a closed submanifold. Then let $M$ be the complement of a tubuler neighborhood of $N$. Similarly, we take two disjoint subset $A,B$ of $\partial M$, and I guess we may define the linking number of the arcs $\alpha$ (whose ends lie on A) and $\beta$ (whose ends lie on B). For the classical case (knots in $S^3$), we can apply Alexander duality, but now it seems that it doesn't work. Also, it's hard to draw a knot (knotted arcs) diagram since $M$ is not $S^3$.

Even the case of closed curves is not carefully described in your post. So it's rather unclear why you think the definition for arcs is not well-defined.

@LeeMosher The case of closed curves is well-known, so I don't think is necessary to define it in detail here. As for the case of arcs, we can count how many times the two arcs intersect (consider the signs of intersections). It's very intuitive to imagine It's well-defined: as you isotope one arc with the ends fixed, the number of signed intersections seems unchanged because a positive and a negative intersections (dis)appear simultaneously,  but I don't know the proof.
